# How to darken overlay background with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

How can I darken the background video in a single line?

I have 2 input streams

1. frame%d.png (series of images frame1.png, frame2.png...)
2. bg.mp4

Currently, I can overlay and scale with the following command,

```
"-i" ,frame%d.png, "-i", bg.mp4,"-r", "30","-filter_complex","scale2ref[a][b];[b][a]overlay", output.mp4
```

but before merge these 2 inputs I want to darken the background.

This is what I have tried

```
ffmpeg -i chunk%d.png -i bg.mp4 -filter_complex "scale2ref[a][b];[b][a]overlay,[1:v]eq='brightness=-0.05'" -y t3.mp4
```

But it resulting in the same merged video without darkening bg.mp4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BG output from scale2ref should be darkened and the result sent as input to the overlay.

```
"[0][1]scale2ref[a][b];[b]eq='brightness=-0.05'[b];[b][a]overlay"
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is `[a][b]` in `scale2ref`?

Comment: They are labels assigned to the output from scale2ref. First output is the resized images. Second output is the reference (BG).